# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 In the Test Class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Hi i am getting List Index out of bounds error, can anyone check my test Class.

Controller :-

```java
public class DOPdf
{
    public list<Delivery_Order__c> delordr{get;set;}
    public Id getid{get;set;} 
    public String phoneNumberBuyer{get;set;}
    public String phoneNumberConsignee{get;set;}
    public String destinationAdd{get;set;}
    public DOPdf(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        getid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        delordr=[Select From_Address__c,To_Address__c,Bill_To__c,Bill_to_If_Direct__c,Dealers__r.Phone__c,Dealers__r.Phone_2__c,Dealers__r.Distributor__r.Phone__c,Dealers__r.Distributor__r.Phone_2__c,
                Sub_Dealer__r.Phone__c,Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c,Sub_Dealer__r.Dealer__r.Phone_2__c, Sub_Dealer__r.Dealer__r.Phone__c,
                DistributorNew__r.Phone__c,DistributorNew__r.Phone_2__c,City__c,Pincode__c,Destination_Address__c from Delivery_Order__c where Id=:getid ORDER BY CreatedDate];
        
             if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Pincode__c))
            {
                destinationAdd= delordr[0].City__c+' - '+ delordr[0].Pincode__c;
            }
           else
           {
               destinationAdd= delordr[0].Destination_Address__c;
           }
            
            If(delordr[0].Bill_To__c == 'Dealer')
            {
                phoneNumberConsignee=delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone__c ;
                if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c))
                {
                   phoneNumberConsignee= phoneNumberConsignee+','+delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c;
                }
                phoneNumberBuyer=delordr[0].Dealers__r.Distributor__r.Phone__c;
                if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Dealers__r.Distributor__r.Phone_2__c))
                {
                   phoneNumberBuyer= phoneNumberBuyer+','+ delordr[0].Dealers__r.Distributor__r.Phone_2__c;
                }
            
            } 
            else If(delordr[0].Bill_To__c == 'Sub-Dealer')
            { 
                phoneNumberConsignee=delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone__c;
                if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c))
                {
                   phoneNumberConsignee= phoneNumberConsignee+','+ delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c;
                }
                phoneNumberBuyer = delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Dealer__r.Phone__c ;
                if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Dealer__r.Phone_2__c))
                {
                   phoneNumberBuyer= phoneNumberBuyer+','+delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Dealer__r.Phone_2__c;
                }
            
            }
            else if(delordr[0].Bill_To__c == 'Direct' )
            {
                if(delordr[0].Bill_to_If_Direct__c == 'Dealer')
                {
                    phoneNumberConsignee= delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone__c ;
                    phoneNumberBuyer= delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone__c ;
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberConsignee= phoneNumberConsignee+','+ delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberBuyer= phoneNumberBuyer+','+delordr[0].Dealers__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                }
                else if(delordr[0].Bill_to_If_Direct__c == 'Sub-Dealer')
                {
                    phoneNumberConsignee = delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone__c ;
                    phoneNumberBuyer = delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone__c ;
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberConsignee= phoneNumberConsignee+','+ delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberBuyer= phoneNumberBuyer+','+delordr[0].Sub_Dealer__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                }
                else if(delordr[0].Bill_to_If_Direct__c =='Distributor')
                {
                    phoneNumberConsignee = delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone__c ; 
                    phoneNumberBuyer = delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone__c;
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberConsignee= phoneNumberConsignee+','+delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                    if(String.isNotBlank(delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone_2__c))
                    {
                       phoneNumberBuyer= phoneNumberBuyer+','+delordr[0].DistributorNew__r.Phone_2__c;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

 }
```

Test Class:-

```java
@isTest 
public class DoPdfTest
{
     static testMethod void Dopdf()
     {
      Dealer__c dlr = new Dealer__c();
      dlr.Name = 'Test Dealer';
        dlr.Phone__c = '123456789';
        dlr.Pincode__c = '234567';
        dlr.Address1__c = 'test address 1';
        dlr.GSTN__c = '29AAACC1206D2ZB';
        dlr.Region__c = 'Bihar';
        dlr.District__c = 'Bhojpur';
        dlr.City__c = 'CHARKHI DADRI';
        dlr.Commission_Rate__c = 23.23;
        dlr.PAN__c = 'CDJNS7339L';
        dlr.Whatsapp_Number2__c = '9876456789';
        dlr.Whatsapp_Number__c  ='3434543456';
        dlr.Latitude__c = 77.2342344;
        dlr.Longitude__c = 98.7876787;
        dlr.TCS_Required__c = 'yes';
        insert dlr;
         
      Delivery_Order__c dlrodr = new Delivery_Order__c();
      dlrodr.From_Address__c = 'Jaipur-302016';
      dlrodr.To_Address__c='6702706 FAX : 6702713';
      dlrodr.Date_Of_Delivery__c = system.today();
      dlrodr.GST__c = '24AAACC1206D1ZM';
      dlrodr.Pincode__c = '666777';
      //dlrodr.Bill_To__c = 'Dealer';
      //dlrodr.Dealers__c = dlr.Id;
      
     insert dlrodr;
     
     Test.StartTest(); 


            
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(dlrodr);
            
            dopdf dopdf1 = new dopdf(sc);
            
            PageReference pageRef = Page.DO_PDF; // Add your VF page Name here
            pageRef.getParameters().put('getid', dlrodr.id);
            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
               
        Test.StopTest();
     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the debug log, you should see that your query for `Delivery_Order__c` returns 0 rows. You then attempt to access index 0 in the list you stored the query results in, but since there are no results (and your list is empty) you get your "List index out of bounds" error.

Including a basic check to make sure that your list isn't empty *before* you try to access an item in the list is probably advisable.

Your test method (the `testmethod` keyword is deprecated, and you should switch to using the `@isTest` annotation for your test methods) does insert some appropriate data for your test, but it has two main issues:

1. You're setting the wrong page parameter in your test. You're setting `getId`, but your code is expecting something in the `id` parameter
2. Your order of operations is wrong here. Your constructor for `DOPdf` expects the `id` parameter, but you don't set that page parameter until after you've called your constructor. You need to swap the order of that in your test (set the page parameter first, then call your constructor)